# Gnuplot svg: change data point color

Tags: svg, colors, gnuplot, datapoint

I am using Gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 2, and want to make an SVG scatter plot with three different datasets. I cannot change the color of the data points.

```
set term svg  enh  size 1800,1800 font "Times,20" rounded background rgb white'
set output 'plot.svg'
set style line 1 lc rgb 'red' pt 7 ps 1 lt 1 lw 2
plot 'data.file' w lp ls 1 ti "Set 1"
```

The data points remain black, but the lines are (correctly) red. This is something unexpected, it works in the other terminals.

Comment: hmmm, I cannot reproduce this with 5.2.2. or other versions. Does it change when you add a `reset session` at the beginning?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in any version of gnuplot. I tried 4.6.6,  5.0 and gnuplot 5.2.2 as reported.   Perhaps the problem is in the viewing program?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the answers! That was the problem... I used Gwenview to look at the output. It colors the lines but not the data points. Inkscape does show it correctly!

Comment: @PeterNemeth.malomsok.good that you found it. Maybe you could write a short answer and accept it yourself. For the sake of not letting this question appear unanswered and according to the SO "rule": no answers in comments. Although it seems trivial, but it might be helpful for other users.